# CRM 2013 : Closed activities navigation missing for system entities

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, microsoft-dynamics

I have a problem with my CRM 2013.
In custom activities, when I open the navigation, I can see both "activities" and "Closed Activities". But if I look in Contact, Account or Lead, I only have "Activities" and the "Closed Activities" is missing.
I think this is not related to my organization since I checked with others and it's the same.

I tried to export the contact entity with one custom entity and I opened customization.xml : The NavBarByRelationshipItem is present in contact (but not in the custom entity where it works...weird...) and it looks totally valid:

```
<NavBarByRelationshipItem RelationshipName="Contact_ActivityPointers" Id="navActivityHistory" TitleResourceId="Tab_Label_History" Icon="/_imgs/ico_18_history.gif" ViewId="21E2B905-6FDB-470d-8517-AD69B4C01268" Sequence="21" Area="Info">
   <Privileges>
     <Privilege Entity="" Privilege="ReadActivity" />
   </Privileges>
   <Titles>
      <Title LCID="1033" Text="Closed Activities" />
   </Titles>
</NavBarByRelationshipItem>
```

Users really want this and I really don't understand why I can't find any info on this problem.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Create a new Form for the entity (i.e. Contact) and publish it. Open a new Contact record using the new Form. If you see that the new Form shows the Closed Activities navigation menu, then download the customization of Contact and compare the FormXml of the original Form and the new Form.